# error page for this type of error - laravel 5

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel-5

in my views/errors/ folder I have several files:
404.blade.php 
503.blade.php

In L5 we can service any error by just putting a file with the error number to the directory.

My problem: how to service this error by a error page:

```
BadMethodCallException in compiled.php line 8273:
Method [int_face] does not exist.
```

As of now I get the

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

Thx

Comment: That's probably just a Error 500

Comment: darn. I just fixed the error. But I added the `500` file. As soon as I screw up sth next, I will see if your solution works! Thank you!

Comment: Just provoke a new error. Like call a class or method that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` usually is a Error code 500.

You can just create a `500.blade.php` file.

Comment: I really don't have a lot of free time at the moment. If you want you can write me an email (it's on my website which is linked in my SO profile) and if I have some time left I'll answer your question(s)